# html: add another class within an anchor

Tags: javascript, html, class

I have this kind of code:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$xml.find( "test" ).each(

         function()
         {                                            
             var state = $(this).attr('state');

             if(state == "known"){   
                $("#mytab").append('<a style="white-space: nowrap" class='+ state +'>' + $(this).text() + '</a><br>' );
             }

         }
);
```

And I want to add another class within the anchor `a` like this:

```
$("#mytab").append('<a style="white-space: nowrap" class="otherClass" class='+ state +'>' + $(this).text() + '</a><br>' );
```

But it doesn't work, because when I see in Chrome debug the class otherClass exists but the class set by the state its no more present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var state='d';
$("#mytab").append('<a style="white-space: nowrap" class="otherClass ' + state +'">sdfsasdfafds</a><br>' );
```

You cannot add two class attribute. You should get it done in a single class attribute.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q87tL9ok/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do the same think but had confusion with quotes and double quotes

Comment: Check out fiddle @Jils

Comment: Its work I just want to say that I had to do the same before asking the question. Your code is ok.